# Updating the index of the parent Swiper from child

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

`Swiper` is a `flutter package`, a feature like a `carousel` of *images/gifs/videos*.

I want to achieve something like this.

I have a parent Widget which is a `Swiper` and it has a child which is a `widget` that contains the *image*, *name*, and *description*.

if I tap the image on the child widget, I want to show the next item of the Swiper / update the index of the Swiper.

**Parent widget**:

```
Swiper(
          index: widget.inititalIndex,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext c, int i) {
            return SwiperContent(
              contentList: widget.contentList,
              selectedIndex: i,
            );
          },
          itemCount: widget.conteList.length,
          loop: false,
          duration: 1000,
        )
```

**SwiperContent widget**:

```
 Widget stackContent() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        //ASSUME I AM ON THE FIRST INDEX
        widget.selectedIndex++;
        //THIS SHOWS THE NEXT ITEM FROM THE LIST BUT WHEN I TRY TO SWIPE RIGHT, THE CONTENT THAT IS SHOWING IS FROM THE NEXT ITEM BUT THE INDEX IS STILL AT 0.
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(contentList[selectedIndex].image),
          Center(
            child: Text(contentList[selectedIndex].description),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to change state `setState` in `onTap`?

Comment: you mean. ```onTap: () {
        //ASSUME I AM ON THE FIRST INDEX
        setState(() {
        widget.selectedIndex++;
      });
        //THIS SHOWS THE NEXT ITEM FROM THE LIST BUT WHEN I TRY TO SWIPE RIGHT, THE CONTENT THAT IS SHOWING IS FROM THE NEXT ITEM BUT THE INDEX IS STILL AT 0.
      },```

Comment: still the same. index is still at 0, but the item showing is from the next index.

Comment: Which `index` are you talking about? Where did you check it?